# Simple inheritance

Tags: java, arrays

I have a superclass called `Employee` and I have to sup classes called `Full_Time` and `Part_Time`
 and have another class called `Company` has a composition relationship with the `Employee` class however 
I wanted to create a method that display's only the Full time data so I wrote the code: -

```
public void display_All_Full (){
    for (int i = 0;i<n_b_E;i++){
        if (a_r_Employee[i] instance_of Full_Time){
            ->a_r_Employee[i].display_Full();
        }
    }
}
```

and then it says error in the line number 3:
 The method `display_Full()` is undefined for the type `Employee`

but I already wrote the method in `Full_Time` class that is a sub class from the super class `Employee`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you need to cast the Employee to a Full_Time employee before executing the method:

```
((Full_Time)a_r_Employee[i]).display_Full();
```

It is safe to do so as you have already confirmed that the employee is of type `Full_Time`

Alternatively, you can make the `Employee` super class an abstract class and then define an abstract method in `Employee`:
e.g.

```
public abstract void display();
```

This then wouldnt need the cast, but you would need to implement the method in every subclass of Employee

Comment: thank you very much that was fast and helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should try to make use of your object hierarchy.  You could define an abstract method in your Employee base class called display().  In each of your subclasses, instead of writing the methods display_Full() or display_Part() you would override display() to do the appropriate implementation for the type of employee that the subclass represents.

Then in your loop, you would simply do:

```
if (a_r_Employee[i] instance_of Full_Time){
    ->a_r_Employee[i].display();
}
```

No casting necessary.

UPDATE:  I didn't notice that the previous answer also suggested the abstract display() method.